# how to fix iphone 13 background scroll when popup is open

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, frontend, mobile-safari

In Iphone 13 Safari browser, I am facing issue of background scroll. When I open a popup the background scrolls, hence I want to stop the background scroll when popup is open. I tried the following code but it seems the issue is not resolving. I hid the overflow on body, applied position fixed and set height to 100vh when popup is open still the scroll issue and its not maintaining the scroll position even though I set a script to scroll to the old position.

The code below is the one I applied -

```
let scrollPos = 0;
const body = document.body;
const overlay = document.querySelector('.popup-overlay');


//popup code
class PopupHome {
  constructor(popup) {
    this.popupOverlay = document.querySelector(".popup-overlay");
    this.popup = popup;
    this.initializePopups();
  }

  initializePopups() {
    // Assign 'click` event handler on the popup trigger button
    this.popup.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const ESCAPE_KEY = "Escape";
      const { popupTrigger } = this.popup.dataset;
      const popupModal = document.querySelector(
        `[data-popup-home="${popupTrigger}"]`
      );

      // Make popup and overlay visible
      popupModal.classList.add("is-visible");
      this.popupOverlay.classList.add("is-overlay");
      document.body.classList.add("popup-open");
      body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      scrollPos = window.scrollY;
      body.style.height = "100vh";
      document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
      document.body.style.top = `0`;
      document.body.style.bottom = `0`;
      document.body.style.margin = `auto`;

      // Add click handler on the popup close button
      popupModal
        .querySelector(".popup__close")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          document.body.classList.remove("popup-open");
          popupModal.classList.remove("is-visible");
          this.popupOverlay.classList.remove("is-overlay");
          body.style.height = "auto"
          body.style.overflow = "visible";
          document.body.style.position = '';
          document.body.style.top = '';
          window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos)
        });

      // Add click handler on the popup overlay to close popup
      this.popupOverlay.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.body.classList.remove("popup-open");
        popupModal.classList.remove("is-visible");
        this.popupOverlay.classList.remove("is-overlay");
        body.style.height = "auto"
        body.style.overflow = "visible";
        document.body.style.position = '';
        document.body.style.top = '';
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos)
      });

      // Add key event handler for "Escape" key to close modal
      window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        this.overlay = document.querySelector(".popup-overlay");
        if (
          event.key === ESCAPE_KEY &&
          popupModal.classList.contains("is-visible") &&
          this.overlay.classList.contains("is-overlay")
        ) {
          document.body.classList.remove("popup-open");
          popupModal.classList.remove("is-visible");
          this.overlay.classList.remove("is-overlay");
          body.style.height = "auto"
          body.style.overflow = "visible";
          document.body.style.position = '';
          document.body.style.top = '';
          window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos)
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to remember the old position. You just need to add `overflow: hidden;` to the body to prevent scrolling on any device.

The steps:

1. click the popup button
2. add `overflow: hidden` to body
3. click the close popup button
4. remove `overflow: hidden` from body

```js
document.querySelector("button.popup-trigger").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("disable-scroll");
  document.querySelector(".popup").classList.add("active");
});

document
  .querySelector("button.close-popup-trigger")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("disable-scroll");
    document.querySelector(".popup").classList.remove("active");
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07) 2px,
      transparent 2px
    ),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07) 2px, transparent 2px),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06) 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
  background-position: -1px -1px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
}

body.disable-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spacer {
  height: 300vh;
}

.popup-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>

<button class="popup-trigger">open popup</button>

<div class="popup">
  popup

  <button class="close-popup-trigger">close popup</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I did but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Bunnings you can try this on ios https://codepen.io/lichingchester/pen/MWQBOgP

Comment: @Bunnings maybe there is something to make your body scrollable, or the background scroll is not on the body... anyway you need to figure out which element you want to prevent scrolling and add overflow hidden to it.